Why is `setblocking(False)` used in Python's socketpair implementation?
I was looking through a Python implementation of socketpair that uses standard sockets. Here's the code snippet I found:
def socketpair(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0):
    if family == AF_INET:
        host = _LOCALHOST
    elif family == AF_INET6:
        host = _LOCALHOST_V6
    else:
        raise ValueError("Only AF_INET and AF_INET6 socket address families "
                            "are supported")
    if type != SOCK_STREAM:
        raise ValueError("Only SOCK_STREAM socket type is supported")
    if proto != 0:
        raise ValueError("Only protocol zero is supported")

    # We create a connected TCP socket. Note the trick with
    # setblocking(False) that prevents us from having to create a thread.
    lsock = socket(family, type, proto)
    try:
        lsock.bind((host, 0))
        lsock.listen()
        addr, port = lsock.getsockname()[:2]
        csock = socket(family, type, proto)
        try:
            csock.setblocking(False)
            try:
                csock.connect((addr, port))
            except (BlockingIOError, InterruptedError):
                pass
            csock.setblocking(True)
            ssock, _ = lsock.accept()
        except:
            csock.close()
            raise
    finally:
        lsock.close()
    return (ssock, csock)

The implementation mentions that setblocking(False) is necessary to "prevent us from having to create a thread," but I can't seem to understand why this is required.
I initially thought that omitting setblocking(False) could lead to a deadlock or blocking behavior, but after testing on both Linux and Windows, the code seems to work fine without it, and the connect call does not block.
So my question is:

What specific issue is setblocking(False) intended to solve here?
Are there platform-specific scenarios or edge cases where the absence of setblocking(False) would cause problems?

Any insight into this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

The initial commit of this code in Python is from asyncio. It's to emulate socketpair on Windows. The code is originally from https://gist.github.com/4325783 by Geert Jansen. The original asyncio repository might have an explanation. Or remove the call and run the asyncio tests on Windows and see if anything fails.

I'll try to attempt the tests tomorrow once I have access to my Windows device again. I also went through the original code discussion but there does not seem to have any discussion about the necessity of a non-blocking connect.

"after testing on both Linux and Windows, the code seems to work fine without [setblocking(False)]" - that would imply the socket is non-blocking to begin with, which it shouldn't be since sockets are supposed to be blocking by default.

@RemyLebeau Is this true though? Does a connect require an accept to happen before it can proceed? I have even tried explicitly replacing it to setblocking(True) and it passes all the tests on Cpython's unit tests after rerunning it as @Schwern suggested.

@RSIMBGO on the server side, TCP connections are completed in the background and queued, and then accept() just pulls from that queue of completed connections. So connect() can return success before accept() is called. That doesn't affect the blocking nature of the client socket in whether connect() waits for the completion or not.

@RemyLebeau Based on your explanation, it seems that connect() waits for the TCP 3-way handshake to complete and does not depend on accept() being called on the server side. If that’s the case, why does that necessitate the non-blocking behaviour of connect()? Even in blocking mode, shouldn’t connect() simply wait for the handshake to finish before returning, without behaving as described in the original explanation by @SteffanUllrich?

@RSIMBGO "it seems that connect() waits for the TCP 3-way handshake to complete" - by default yes, unless set to non-blocking, then it returns as soon as the handshake is begun. "why does that necessitate the non-blocking behaviour of connect()" - platform-dependent. Some systems finish the handshake only when accept() is called. Other systems finish the handshake in the background and queue the connection for accept(). The Python code can't assume the server's implementation, so is coded in a way that would work for all systems...

@RSIMBGO "Even in blocking mode, shouldn’t connect() simply wait for the handshake to finish before returning" - it does wait. The issue is when the handshake is finished - on the accept() call or not.

@RemyLebeau I see, if there is a platform that finishes the handshake only when accept() is called, then I understand. Is there any known specific platform that exhibits this behaviour?

The code is initiating a non-blocking connect to another socket within the same thread, i.e.

create server (listener) socket lsock and client socket csock
initiate non-blocking connect from csock to lsock
accept this connect on lsock, returning ssock

The non-blocking connect in (2) returns immediately, even if the socket is not yet accepted (3). If instead a blocking connect would be used then it would hang in (2) until accept gets called in (3), which would never happen because it hangs in (2).
The alternative would be to do a blocking connect and a blocking accept in separate threads. Hence the comment:
# ... Note the trick with
# setblocking(False) that prevents us from having to create a thread


I have thought about this as well, but I tried commenting out the setblocking(False) in the code to see if I can replicate this blocking behaviour to no avail. Is there any way to replicate this blocking behaviour?

@RSIMBGO setblocking(False) is really setting a 0 timeout. I wonder if usually the socket is created with a 0 timeout, but there's a condition where the socket can begin with a non-zero timeout. https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts

@SteffenUllrich "If instead a blocking connect would be used then it would hang in (2) until accept gets called in (3), which would never happen because it hangs in (2)" - that is the scenario that the code is trying to avoid. However, on Linux, for example, the handshake is completed in the background and the completed connection is put into a queue before accept() ever sees it. In that scenario, a blocking connect() would be released before accept() is called.
